# How to change all windows user passwords using cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Well, I made this code and I think some of you will need it.

The code changes passwords of all windows users using cmd in one line

Comment: Technically, you're supposed to pose a question here, not make a statement. You have answered a question which was never posed.

Comment: You may post a question and an instant self-answer, but still please ensure to ask an on-topic question; refer to [ask] for that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %x in ('dir /B "%systemdrive%\users" ^| findstr /l /v Public') do (net user "%x" "Example")
```

The password will become an `Example` for all accounts on the device

Comment: That code does not perform the task you've stated. It does not deal with all accounts on the device. It is limited only to accounts, not named `Public` which have not undergone a name change since creation, and were specifically set up in a one particular directory path. It also will not work for any accounts if run from a batch file, _(one of your tags)_, and would also need elevation or particular permissions.